# App freezes while parsing json data

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

after I implemented a JSON parser in my app the app behaves weirdly.It doesn't give any error while it freezes on the progress dialog as I run the app and it is unable to fetch the data and if I remove the progressdialog it says recyclerview not attached skipping frame

Here's my code

MainActivity

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Config;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader.RecyclerViewHeader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    ImageView image;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personProf;
     private RecyclerView rv;
    private List<Person> persons;
    ImageView images;
    RecyclerViewHeader header;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ImageView iv;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public String strurl;
    URL url;
    URI uri;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        personName= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        personProf=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        images= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));


        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Capsule");
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        //setPalette();
        strurl =  "http://www.humanfox.com/capsule/assets/img/jawed_headshot.jpg";

        Typeface face2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface face4= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Javed-Habib_11.jpg")
                .into(image);

       rv =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
       rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
       llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        header = (RecyclerViewHeader) findViewById(R.id.header);
        header.attachTo(rv,true);
        //initializeData();
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        getData();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(COnfig.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                         loading.dismiss();

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                person.setImageUrl(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                person.setName(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_NAME));
                person.setPassion(json.getString(COnfig.TAG_PROFESSION));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            persons.add(person);
        }

        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new RVAdapter(persons, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.media.Image;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c. dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    private ImageLoader imageloader;
    private Context context;

    List<Person> persons;

     public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons,Context context){
         super();
         this.persons = persons;
         this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,null);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        Person person = persons.get(i);
        imageloader=CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageloader.get(person.getImageUrl(),ImageLoader.getImageListener(personViewHolder.personPhoto,R.drawable.ic_launcher,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageUrl(person.getImageUrl(),imageloader);
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(person.getName());
        personViewHolder.personProf.setText(person.getPassion());


    }






    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }

    class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cv;
        public TextView personName;
        public TextView personProf;
        public NetworkImageView personPhoto;
        //public Context ctx;

        public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            personProf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            personPhoto=(NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't parse JSON on your main thread.

Comment: Firstly you need to be doing any network operations asynchronously, off the main UI thread.  Secondly while doing asynchronous tasks on a background thread you have to be aware of runtime configuration changes - basically activities can come and go so you may end up with a null object reference when the asynchronous task completes.  I'd look into using AsyncTask using a retained headless fragment with callbacks simple reference - http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/

Comment: i have followed a tutorial.[link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-with-images-using-recyclerview-and-volley/). I did something similar to that but doesnt works